# PHP - SimpleHTMLDom - How to access table elements?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to grab the artists for every album release based on metacritic using simplehtmldom - http://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/release-date/coming-soon/date?view=detailed

The artist names are contained within seperate td elements which have the class name of artistName

What I've managed to figure out so far is

```
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/release-date/coming-soon/date?view=detailed');
    $es = $html->find('table.musicTable td');
```

Where do I go from here? I'm finding examples and the documentation a bit confusing. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the PHP:DOM extension
[DOM manual here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

which is a very powerful tools for parsing and manipulating XML or HTML documents

for your case you can do like this

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/release-date/coming-soon/date?view=detailed');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$searchNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName("table"); 

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
{ 
    //do your things here
} 
?>
```

or even can use xpath to query the document node

[Xpath usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Answer (score 1):

Every name is contained into an anchor inside a `<td class="artistName">`, that's all what needed in this case to create the following code:

```
$url = "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/release-date/coming-soon/date?view=detailed";

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load_file($url);

// Find the anchor containing the name inside all "td.artistName" elements
$anchors = $html->find('td.artistName a');

// loop through all found anchors and print the content
foreach($anchors as $anchor) {

    $name = $anchor->plaintext;

    echo $name . "<br>";
}

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

*OUTPUT*

```
Peter Gabriel 
Stephen Malkmus & The Jicks 
TOY 
Black Knights 
Broken Bells 
Bruce Springsteen 
David Broza 
Eskimo Callboy 
...
```

<kbd>[Working DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i93-62p)</kbd>

Please read the [`MANUAL`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more examples and details